# dynamical appended vuejs content: scope.test is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to find a workable solution for following scenario:

1. vuejs will render its "main" content first;
2. when some click happen, it loads some vuejs aware html(including both component referring and its data);
3. that dynamically loaded vuejs partial html should be compiled and inserted to a pre-defined node(mount point).

I am now trying to use the $mount functionality to give a try.
You can have a check on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/matiascx/cd35khy8/
Also, i paste code here:

```
<div id="app">
  <button v-on="click: addNewElement()">Add custom Element</button> 
  <br />
  <div id="dynamicloaded"></div>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    sampleElement: '<div><button v-on="click: test()">Test</button></div>'
  },
  methods:{
    addNewElement: function(){
      var vmtemp = Vue.extend({
                        template: this.sampleElement,
                        methods: {}
                   });
      new vmtemp().$mount(document.getElementById('dynamicloaded'));
    },
    test: function(){
       alert('Test');
    }
  }
});
```

The vuejs always complain:

```
VM1881:3 Uncaught TypeError: scope.test is not a function
```

I am wondering it is because wrong scope assigned to newly mounted content.

1. How to fix it? thanks to @gurghet, he has pointed out the issue is caused by new mounted 'component' can not access the test function which is in root scope.
2. Is that the proposed way to achieve that goal (dynamically compile and mounted count with right scope)
   Thanks to @gurghet, I bring up more practical questions about this ticket:
3. How let that test function defined within parent be available to that dynamically mounted component?                                                    4. Why the dynamically mounted component has no child-parent relationship with root vue instance? How to let they have the parent-child relationship?                   Thanks~!

Comment: You should add the `test` method on `vmtemp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you debug your application you will find that the method `test` is not present in the options. This is because is a method of the 'father'.

You should add the method test directly in the `methods:{}` of the `dynamicloaded`

http://jsfiddle.net/L25oqe5n/

Comment: @gughet, you are right, the test function is not accessible in the dynamically loaded and compiled mounted content. My question is:  1. How let that test function defined within parent be available to that dynamically mounted component?  2. Why the dynamically mounted component has no child-parent relationship with root vue instance? How to let they have the parent-child relationship?  Thanks~!

Comment: Those are 2  very good questions for stackoverflow! Since they are applicable to a broad range of users I suggest you to write them separately as questions. I would be a pity to only have the answer in a comment.

Comment: @gughet, thanks for your time and response, i have added the 2 additional question to the question title/description section. Any guidance on how to tackle this is highly appreciated

Comment: Thanks, but I meant two separate questions. It would be very confusing to have 3 questions in one.

Comment: i have create another stackoverflow ticket, you can give more comments on that thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307070/why-dynamically-mounted-vuejs-content-is-not-child-component-of-root-vue-instanc