# why dynamically mounted vuejs content is not child component of root vue instance?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I load some html containing customized component, and mount that content to a fixed node in parent component. Unfortunately, i found there is no parent-child relationship between them, so the events dispatched by dynamically inserted component can not be received by root vue.
I have created one fiddle, any help or proposal is appreciated!.
http://jsfiddle.net/matiascx/7Ljygv81/1/

```
<div id="app">
    <button v-on="click: addNewElement()">Add custom Element</button> 
    <br />
    <div id="dynamicloaded"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        sampleElement: '<div class="dynamic-child"><button v-on="click: test()">Test</button></div>'

    },
    methods:{
        addNewElement: function(){



           var vmtemp = Vue.extend({
                            template: this.sampleElement,
                            methods: {
                             test: function(){
                               alert("comes from dynamically loaded content");
                               this.$dispatch('child-msg','this comes from ajax loaded component');
                             }
                            }
                        });
           new vmtemp().$mount(document.getElementById('dynamicloaded'));
        },
        test: function(){
           alert('Test');
        },
        events: {
         'child-msg': function(msg){
            console.log('message received'+msg);
         }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to the vuejs creator's help, i have tried async component approach, it really works and right parent-child relationship setup when after dynamic content rendered into dom.
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3255#issuecomment-231686976

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you create dynamically a Vue component is not child of any particular instance. You can set the parent explicitly within the options

```
var _this = this
var child = new vmtemp({parent:_this}).$mount(document.getElementById('dynamicloaded'))
```

Inside your `addNewElement` function.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: i have updated the fiddle according to your proposal, it does not work. For a normal component, it works well for the event system, that is the evidence for normal component can live as child for root. But the dynamically mounted 'component' can not be set as child component for root vue instance

Comment: it does not work, can you have other ideas other than new vmtemp({parent:_this}).$mount?