# Function call inside a template

Tags: javascript, laravel, scope, vue.js

I have a vue component for simple pagination of a table. I need to highlight a row of said table on mouse over. What I did so far is create the template and create the dynamically loaded ajax powered next and previous buttons. The issue is that highlighting because its a dynamic element.

Here is the template code:

```
<tbody class="table-body">
    <template id="template-student">
        <tr @mouseover="highlightRow()" class="students-row" data-student-url="{{ URL::route("student", 1) }}">
            <td>
                <div class="student-image">
                    <div class="flag"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="">@{{ student.student_firstname }}</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="">@{{ student.student_lastname }}</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @{{ student.student_telephone }}
            </td>
            <td>
                @{{ student.student_fathersname }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </template>
</tbody>
```

And the vue code:

```
Vue.component('student', {
    template: '#template-student',
    props: ['student'],
  });
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      students: [],
      pagination: {}
    },
    ready() {
      this.fetchStudents();
    },
    methods: {
      fetchStudents(pageNumber) {
        if (pageNumber === undefined) {
          pageNumber = 1;
        }
        const vm = this;
        const pageUrl = `/api/on-roll/all/${pageNumber}`;
        this.$http.get(pageUrl)
            .then((response) => {
              vm.makePagination(response.data.pagination);
              vm.$set('students', response.data.data);
        });

      },
      makePagination(data) {
        const pagination = {
          current_page: data.current_page,
          total_pages: data.total_pages,
          next_page: data.next_page,
          prev_page: data.prev_page
        };
        this.$set('pagination', pagination);
      },
      highlightRow(){
        console.log("test")
      }

    }
  });
```

The issue is when I hover over any row I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: scope.highlightRow is not a function
```

Now I understand (more or less) why is this happening, I am calling a function inside the template tags (if I cal outside on a example element it works). Some research lead me to this question [dynamical appended vuejs content: scope.test is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38299400/dynamical-appended-vuejs-content-scope-test-is-not-a-function) But the help there didn't help me. I couldn't figure out how to implement the solution to my example.

Comment: Just do it in CSS, you don't need any code here: `tr:hover td { background: red; }`.

Comment: Ah, it worked. Still I would like an actually solution for this because I need this to work for other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you want a component to have access to something from a parent, pass it in as a prop.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    myComponent: {
      template: '<div @mouseover="onHover">Hi</div>',
      props: ['onHover']
    }
  },
  methods: {
    highlightRow() {
      console.log('test');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-component :on-hover="highlightRow"></my-component>
</div>
```